TypeScript mistype
I'm trying to realize a function so that my component's columns can slide and be reordered according to what the user wants. However, the function is giving me a TypeScript typing error, saying that the function implicitly has the type any.
  const onDragEnd = ({ active, over }: DragEndEvent) => {
    if (active.id !== over?.id) {
      setStocksSelected(previous => {
        const activeIndex = previous.findIndex((i: any) => i.key === active.id);
        const overIndex = previous.findIndex((i: any) => i.key === over?.id);
        return arrayMove(previous, activeIndex, overIndex);
      });
    }
  };

But when reporting the type as stocks[], it persists in reporting a typing error
Error: Argument of type '(previous: Stocks[]) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Stocks[]'.ts(2345)
The function has the return type 'any', implicitly, because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.
  const onDragEnd = ({ active, over }: DragEndEvent) => {
    if (active.id !== over?.id) {
      setStocksSelected((previous: Stocks[]) => {
        const activeIndex = previous.findIndex((i: any) => i.key === active.id);
        const overIndex = previous.findIndex((i: any) => i.key === over?.id);
        return arrayMove(previous, activeIndex, overIndex);
      });
    }
  };

I couldn't understand what should be done. I would be grateful if anyone could help me.
Below is the implementation of setStocksSelected
import { create } from 'zustand';
import Stocks from '~/@core/domain/model/stock/Stocks';

interface IGfpService {
  stocks: Stocks[];
  setStocks: (stockValues: Stocks[]) => void;
  stocksSelected: Stocks[],
  setStocksSelected: (stockSelectedValues: Stocks[]) => void,
}

const useGfpStore = create<IGfpService>()(set => ({
  stocks: [],
  setStocks: stockValues => set({ stocks: stockValues }),
  stocksSelected: [],
  setStocksSelected: stockSelectedValues => set({ stocksSelected: stockSelectedValues }),
}));

export default useGfpStore;

arrayMove It's a library
For example importation:
import { SortableContext, arrayMove, useSortable, verticalListSortingStrategy } from '@dnd-kit/sortable'; 


what's arrayMove?

Can you show setStocksSelected and arrayMove?

arrayMove It's a library
import {
SortableContext,
arrayMove,
useSortable,
verticalListSortingStrategy
} from '@dnd-kit/sortable';

Edited with updated data

setStocksSelected((previous: Stocks[]): Stocks[] => {

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] (look at that link to see what that means) so that we can copy and paste your example into our own IDEs and see your problem without other distracting problems (like lack of Stocks definition, etc.). Ideally you should do this from scratch and not just give us excerpts of a code base with dependencies on third-party or private stuff. Good luck!
